# self-service APIs error response has multiple formats

Tags: amadeus

When I test self-service APIs, I found that there are 2 different formats for the error response.

- case 1: when there is something wrong with token
  I got such response

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "38190",
            "title": "Invalid access token",
            "detail": "The access token provided in the Authorization header is invalid",
            "status": "401"
        }
    ]
}
```

- case 2: for other scenario such as INVALID DATE, MANDATORY DATA MISSING etc.
  I got the error with another format

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 4926,
      "title": "INVALID DATA RECEIVED",
      "detail": "travelerType value is not in the allowed enumeration",
      "source": {
        "pointer": "/travelers[0]/travelerType",
        "example": "ADULT"
      },
      "status": 400
    }
  ]
}
```

The value of "code" and "status" have type `string` in case 1, but have type `int` in case 2.

Is it normal that the access token error has a particular error response format? Thanks

Comment: You are right, there is no particular reason to have a string here. Thanks for raising this issue, I have shared the feedback with the API development team. We will update the answer as soon as I have more information.

Comment: We have fixed this inconsistency the `code` and the `status` are now integers everywhere.

Comment: @AnthonyRoux I made a test, and it is fixed for the self service APIs, thanks! But it seems that the entreprise APIs still have this issue, could you also fix it for entreprise APIs please?